# How to rename a variable coming into a Function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, renaming

Trying to rename this variable: `assetPayoutType` to just `payType`, however because I'm working in TypeScript there is a problem. TypeScript thinks there is a type called `payType`.

```
const { title, assetPayoutType } = this.props;

mapDailyAssets(assetPayoutType: string)
```

IE: This won't work:

```
mapDailyAssets(assetPayoutType: payType: string)
```

---

I searched on StackOverflow and found two answers that did not answer this question.

**Answer describes a non-typescript / regular Javascript simple rename:**

[Renaming remaining properties variable when object destructuring in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318640/renaming-remaining-properties-variable-when-object-destructuring-in-typescript)

**This answer is about VSCode refactoring:**

[TypeScript rename variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699643/typescript-rename-variable?rq=1)

Comment: After adding the new name you have to remove the old name as well?

Comment: Just realized I could rename the variable higher up in my logic, when it comes through `this.props` I think there is no way to rename a variable this way with Typescript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`type` is protected word (keyword) in Typescript

also:

`const { title, assetPayoutType: payoutType } = this.props;`